# Changing Javascript History

Tags: javascript, url-rewriting, history, back-button

When I load my php page I append some data. For instance MyPage.php?value=something.
As expected, when I go back and forth using the back button, it always loads with that same data appended. I don't want that. I want that after the page loads, I should be able to change the history to store only MyPage.php WITHOUT the appended data.So now when I would use the back button it would load MyPage.php only. How can I do this - javascript, jquery, php , anything???

If there is a way to do that without touching the history object, thats also fine. I'm just assumng it'll take some history tweaking. I'm also OK if it takes tweaking on the client or server side.

Comment: You know, your users may consider browser history to be a **feature**.  Even if you want to disable it, they may not, and ultimately the browser is running on *their* computer, not yours.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, it is not possible to tweak the history like that, nor is it a good way to deal with this.

You could use a cookie to determine when a page gets loaded more than twice, or store the data in a session variable instead, and delete it once your processing is done.

Answer (score 1):

I assume the data is appended by using GET method. Using POST will not append text after MyPage.php but still can pass data to the page.

Answer (score 0):

The history is the history.  It's a bit of a hack to go changing that (and you will probably have other issues down the road if you do).

It is better to either have NO querystring at all, and use js or server-side logic to determine the action, or to have js or server-side logic to ignore the second request.

Answer (score 0):

If you are fine with tweaking the history then you can probably look in to this.

```
history.replaceState({}, document.title, "MyPage.php");
```

This will rewrite the current window.location to "MyPage.php" without page refresh.